# Getting Real time traffic with Zabbix

Tags: networking, snmp, traffic, zabbix

I want to monitor real time traffic of a specific port in a switch with zabbix through snmp. I have enabled snmp on switch, and can retrieve data via snmpwalk and snmpget and also I can monitor some parameters from the switch via zabbix.So far everything is good. My problem is that I want to get the real time network traffic, I mean for example when I set Update interval to 60, I expect take the inbound/outbound traffic of a port within the last 1 minute. By now I am using IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.10001 which reveals the traffic since that switch has been turned on!!
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In item configuration, change "Store value" from "As is" to "Delta (speed per second)".

Please refer to the [Item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/item) and [SNMP](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/snmp) documentation, as well as "Template SNMP Interfaces" that comes with Zabbix by default.

Comment: Thank you @asaveljevs for your answer. My problem has been solved with your help. Honestly I used Delta (simple change) because I want the traffic itself not the traffic rate or bandwidth.